# How do I host a Google Cloud Platform project on a subdomain for an existing site?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up a custom domain for a Google Cloud Project that I own.  I want to map the project to the subdomain of a site that we already use.  So, for example, I have an app that lives at `https://docket-tracker.appspot.com/` and I want to host it at `https://dockets.example.com/`.  We already use `https://www.example.com/`, `https://example.com/`, and several other subdomains on that domain.

I went through the [documentation that Google gives](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app) to generate the DNS records that I need, and it tells me this:

```
Add the following DNS records with your domain registrar for example.com:
Type    Data                    Alias
A       216.239.32.21   
A       216.239.34.21   
A       216.239.36.21   
A       216.239.38.21   
AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::15   
AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::15   
AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::15   
AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::15   
CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com    dockets 

DNS changes can take up to 24 hours to take effect.
Your SSL certificate will take several minutes to activate.
```

Notice on the first line that it specifies `example.com`.  Why is it telling me to put all these records on the top level domain?  I don't want to have `example.com` go to any of these, I want to have `dockets.example.com` go to these.  How do I host on `dockets.example.com` **without** messing with the A records I already use at the top level domain?

In case it's helpful, the DNS we are using is [Pair](https://www.pairdomains.com/kb/categories/3)

**Edit:** 
I think the source of my confusion can be summed up in like so.  When creating a custom domain, I unselect the option to map to any domain/subdomain *other than* `dockets.example.com`.  Yet I am still told to add a bunch of A/AAAA records changing the naked domain.  Why does it tell me to do this?  My inclination is to ignore it and only use the CNAME provided.
[image: DNS records it gives me]
My inclination is further reinforced by the fact that those A records disappear when I navigate to App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains.
[image: DNS records it gives me without A records]
So I suppose my question is: can I ignore those A records and only use the CNAME, and if not, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommends mapping the DNS Root Zone (example.com) in addition to any subdomains that you intend to use. This is a suggestion, not a requirement.

In the event, you only want to map a subdomain (dockets.example.com) then only create an App Engine custom domain for that domain (dockets.example.com).

Comment: Okay, so basically if I only want the subdomain, I would only add the CNAME record in my DNS and ignore the A/AAAA records?

Comment: No, you need to create a new custom domain for the one you want. Delete the old custom domain first.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do I need to remake the custom URL?  Or rather, what would I change if I remade it?  When "Pointing my Domain to Docket-tracker", I don't map www.example.com or example.com.  I only map dockets.example.com.  Which is why I'm confused about it giving me a bunch of A/AAAA records and telling me to add them to the naked domain in the "Update your DNS records to enable security" step.  Also, if I click "done", and go back to the customs domain tab, it no longer even shows the A/AAAA records, just the CNAME.  So do I even need those A records?  Or only use the CNAME?

Comment: Your statement does not match the details in your question. If you want a custom domain set up for `dockets.example.com` you need to follow the documentation and create one. The details in your question created a custom domain for `example.com`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why I am confused!  The records provided to me create a custom domain for example.com, and I don't understand why, because it seems like that isn't what I've asked for.  I've added more to my original question to elaborate on this.

Comment: Have you configured the records as displayed, waited a day (for DNS to become active worldwide) and then tested?

Comment: No, because I am very skeptical about changing the A records for my naked domain.  I don't want to affect example.com

Comment: Don't change the DNS Root Zone. Only add the subdomain and the CNAME.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand, I don't do anything with the A records?  I only add the CNAME of ghs.googlehosted.com for dockets.example.com?

Comment: If you configured the custom domain correctly in GCP, yes.